# Swift: first day of the week in app doesn't change after I change it in Settings

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, date, calendar

In my app I need to group different items based on their date, so I need a method to get date of the beginning of the week, and also a method to find out if two dates are in the same week. However, I get unexpected problems trying to implement this.

I use this code to get the first day of the week:

```
return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
```

I use `Calendar.current`, but it returns the same day no matter which day is chosen as the beginning of the week in iOS Settings.

To check if two dates are in the same week I use this code:

```
    func isInSameWeek(date: Date) -> Bool { isEqual(to: date, toGranularity: .weekOfYear) }
```

Still, Sunday and Monday dates are always considered not in the same week no matter which day is chosen as the beginning of the week in iOS Settings.

How do I fix this? Or maybe it is a normal behavior and this code will work correctly for users in different regions?

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the settings of the Calendar App not the iOS current calendar itself. You need to provide your own app settings to be changed by the user.

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 2
calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))?.description(with: .current)  // "Monday, September 14, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM Brasilia Standard Time"
```